# API not working after installing SSL on kong

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, kong

im following docs at https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/acme/#example-config to install SSL certificate. But after i successfully installed it, i cant call any of my APIs anymore, it shows `{"message":"no Route matched with those values"}`. What am i missing here?

kong.yml

```
_format_version: "2.1"

_transform: true

services:
  - name: acme-dummy
    url: http://127.0.0.1:65535
    routes:
      - name: acme-dummy
        protocols:
          - http
        paths:
          - /.well-known/acme-challenge

  - name: notification
    url: https://notification-app:2030/

  ...

routes:
  - name: notification-routes
    service: notification
    paths: ['/notification/*']

  ...

plugins:
  - name: cors
    route: notification-routes
    config:
        origins:
        - http://localhost:3000
        methods:
        - GET
        - POST
        headers:
        - Accept
        - Accept-Version
        - Authorization
        - Content-Length
        - Content-MD5
        - Content-Type
        - Date
        - X-Auth-Token
        exposed_headers:
        - X-Auth-Token
        credentials: true
        max_age: 3600
        preflight_continue: false
  ...

  # ACME Plugin
  - name: acme
    config:
      account_email: 123@gmail.com
      domains:
        - "somehost.com"
      tos_accepted: true
      storage: postgres
      storage_config:
        redis:
          host: kong-postgres
          port: 6432
```

docker.compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
    kong-gateway:
        external: false
        name: kong-gateway
    microservices:
        external: true
        name: microservices

volumes:
    pg-volumes:
        name: kong-postgres

services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:13.3-alpine
        container_name: kong-postgres
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
            - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
        ports:
            - "${POSTGRES_PORT}:5432"
        volumes:
            - pg-volumes:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        networks:
            - kong-gateway

    kong:
        container_name: kong-gateway
        image: kong/kong-gateway:2.4.1.0-alpine
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "80:8000"
            - "443:8443"
            - "127.0.0.1:8001:8001"
            - "127.0.0.1:8444:8444"
        environment:
            - KONG_DATABASE=postgres
            - KONG_PG_HOST=kong-postgres
            - KONG_PG_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
            - KONG_PG_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
            - KONG_PG_DATABASE=${POSTGRES_DB}

            - KONG_LUA_SSL_TRUSTED_CERTIFICATE=system
            - KONG_DECLARATIVE_CONFIG=/usr/local/kong/declarative/kong.yml
            - KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=logs/access.log
            - KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=logs/access.log
            - KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=logs/error.log
            - KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=logs/error.log
            - KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl
        volumes:
            - ./kong-volume:/usr/local/kong/declarative
            - ./kong.conf:/etc/kong/kong.conf:ro
        networks:
            - kong-gateway
            - microservices
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        # command: kong migrations bootstrap
```

also when i run `docker logs` no error shown. And when i try to get the certificate with `curl http://localhost:8001/acme/certificates/{HOST} -XGET` it return the certificate successfully. Any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You configure your route to only listen on http

```
services:
  - name: acme-dummy
    url: http://127.0.0.1:65535
    routes:
      - name: acme-dummy
        protocols:
          - http
```

As said into the [doc](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/reference/proxy/#restricting-the-client-protocol)

> Routes have a protocols property to restrict the client protocol they should listen for.

Just add `https` or replace `http` with `https` if you only want to listen on https

```
services:
  - name: acme-dummy
    url: http://127.0.0.1:65535
    routes:
      - name: acme-dummy
        protocols:
          - http
          - https
```

or

```
services:
  - name: acme-dummy
    url: http://127.0.0.1:65535
    routes:
      - name: acme-dummy
        protocols:
          - https
```

Comment: thank you for ur response, but it still not working

Comment: Is the call working with http ? Can you share the curl done ?

Comment: the http also didnt work and show the same response `{"message":"no Route matched with those values"}`. Also when i tried to run the kong without DB (DB LESS), the api is back to work (with http)

Answer (score 0):

My workarround right now is to copy the certificate from the db and put it on kong.yml like this:

```
certificates:
  - snis:
      - name: site.com
    cert: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      ...
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    key: |
      -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
      ...
      -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

still this not answering the question, but this method actually works...